# How to validate Hall Ticket number of particular format

Tags: javascript, string, validation

I am doing a project that displays the semester wise marks according to the given HallTicket Number.

So, I have to provide validation for entered Hall ticket number using JavaScript.

And hall ticket number has following constraints:

```
--->It shouid hav exactly 10 characters
--->starting two positions may be 10 or 11 or 12
--->next four positions must be the string "kp1a"
--->later two positions may contains any of 02 or 04 or 05 or 12 only
--->remaing two positions may any digits from 01 to 60.
```

Can any one say how to write JavaScript for validating this kind of Hall ticket number?

Comment: Yes kTekkie!What i hav tried is that if we submit the form with out giving hall ticket number the it will display an alert like "Hall Ticket Number required."Since i'm new to javascript i'm struggling how to validate it for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a (slightly tested) non-regex solution

```
function validateTicketNum(numb){
   var first = ["10","11","12"];
   var third = ["02","04","05","12"];
   if (numb.length!==10){
      return false;
   }
   else if (first.indexOf(numb.substring(0,2))==-1){
      return false;
   }
   else if (numb.substring(2,6)!=='kp1a'){
      return false;
   }
   else if (third.indexOf(numb.substring(6,8))==-1){
      return false;
   }
   else if (isNaN(numb.substring(8,10)) || 
            parseInt(numb.substring(8,10),10) < 1 ||
            parseInt(numb.substring(8,10),10) > 60){
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```